# Rails - eager loading detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eager-loading

I have 3 associated tables: `Elment`, `Measurement` and `Image`.

Element `has_many` Measurements

Measurements `has_many` Images, also Images `has_many` Measurements (N-N association)

---

How can I minimize number of queries in

```
images = @element.measurements.map {|e| e.images}.reject!(&:blank?)
images.flatten.map {|i| i.file.url}
```

For this code, there are N queries for every measurement. Can I minimize this with something like this:

```
@element.measurements.joins(:images).select('images.file')
```

Query: `

```
SELECT "images.file" FROM "measurements" 
INNER JOIN "images" ON "element_images"."measurement_id" = "measurements"."id" 
INNER JOIN "images" ON "element_images"."id" = "images"."image_id" 
WHERE "measurements"."element_id" = $1`
```

Comment: `joins(element: :images)` should probably do.

Comment: I think `includes(element: :images)` is more appropriate

Comment: Both are returning active record association relation. What am I missing? 
@LuizE. I was using joins for select. 
`Measurement::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`

Comment: did you do `@element.measurements.includes(images: :measurements).select('images.file')`? it might work

Comment: Stil returning relation. But in console I see query for loading images. 
SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" IN (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)` 
Tried without `select` and I got `Measuremets` without `images`.

Comment: Can't you use that `Relation` object?  Maybe `your_relation.each` ? There you should have the model instances

Comment: Yes I can. Didn't know that. Thaks guys for your help.
My solution is: 
`images = Measurement.where(element_id: @element.id).includes(:element_images)
        images = images.map {|e| e.element_images}.reject!(&:blank?).flatten`

Answer (score 1):

Here is step by step replacing:

```
images = @element.measurements.map {|e| e.images}.reject!(&:blank?)
```

For this line of code it is better to produce next relation

```
has_many :images, through: :measurements
# OR for better naming
has_many :measurement_images, through: :measurements, source: :images
```

Then you can just do:

```
images = @element.measurement_images
```

Which will execute next SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM images 
INNER JOIN measurements 
ON measurements.id = images.measurement_id
WHERE measurements.element_id = $1
```

So no need to reject blank images as `INNER JOIN` just do exactly that, throws away non-matching records, check out [the doc](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

After creating this `has_many through` relation, next code won't produce any N+1 issues:

```
images.map {|i| i.file.url}
```

Also you can minimize the output by adding `#select`, but I don't advise you to do that, as it complicates code a lot and heavily coupled on image library implementation, so in case of updating library you can break the code. 
But for note, if you use `paperclip` gem with default URL generation pattern you can do something like this:

```
image_ulrs = @element
  .measurement_images
  .select(
    :id,
    :type, # if you have STI model
    :<your_file_field>_file_name, 
    :<your_file_field>_updated_at
  ).map { |i| i.file.url }
```

**`<your_file_field>`** is the first argument which is passed to `has_attached_file` for example

```
has_attached_file :attachment
```

will result in

```
  ...  
  .select(
    :id,
    :type, # if you have STI model
    :attachment_file_name, 
    :attachment_updated_at
  )
```

but again I do **NOT** suggest to do that as it does not give a lot of performance improvement but can be a headache in future.